# Mininet custom topology with multiple remote controllers

Tags: networking, simulation, sdn, mininet, opendaylight

I am totally new in mininet and SDN domain.

I would like to implement custom mininet topology, which is connected to multiple remote controllers.

Currently, I have planned to use mininet as SDN network emulator and OpenDaylight as a controller for my testbed.

Is there any tutorial or link for custom topology with multiple remote controller implementation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of examples on the Mininet GitHub repository [examples](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/tree/master/examples)

I think that for what you are trying to do you should have a look at [multiController example](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/controllers.py).

Comment: I implemented [link] (https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/controllers.py) multiController example as you mentioned in above, however, ping reachability failed between hosts when I connected the mininet to remote controller.

Comment: @RazielNaing be sure to correctly configure the controllers.

Comment: Could you suggest me any tutorial or website links for the configuration? Thank you.